# H2 DB: How to check whether table schema is initialized programmatically?

Tags: java, h2

I have a DB schema that creates several tables and fills them with data. I want to check whether db contains corresponding tables or not during app start. I could check for db file existence, but H2 creates db if it doesn't exist. So the only way, I think, is to check for tables existence.

Here is the code of how I initialize DB:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:database/svc", "sa", "");

Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100), record INT, record_date DATE, UNIQUE(name))");
st.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100), record INT, record_date DATE, UNIQUE(name))");
st.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS daily_record_stat (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, date DATE, table1_id INT, table1_record INT, table2_id INT," +
            " table2_record INT, total_record INT);");
st.execute("ALTER TABLE daily_record_stat ADD FOREIGN KEY (table1_id) REFERENCES table1(id);");
st.execute("ALTER TABLE daily_record_stat ADD FOREIGN KEY (table2_id) REFERENCES table2(id);");
st.execute("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1, 'non_existed_stub', 0, NULL)");
st.execute("INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(1, 'non_existed_stub', 0, NULL)");

conn.close();
```

As you see, I check for table existence before creation using `IF NOT EXISTS` statement. But then I run at the problem with `ALTER` and `INSERT` - these commands don's allow IF usage.

I tried to do the following:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:database/svc", "sa", "");
ResultSet meta = conn.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "table1", null);
if(meta.next()) {
    //do something
}
```

But `meta.next()` is `false`.

So how to check whether table schema is initialized? Or maybe this should be done some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you mean by saying to check programmatically, buy you can try to use `DatabaseMetaData.getTables()`. This call will return `ResultSet` which you'll have to check programmatically. You can see what fields are returned in this `ResultSet` in corresponding section [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html). And meta data itself can be obtained by `conn.getMetaData()`.

Following code should return all tables which names start with 'TABLE':

```
ResultSet meta = conn.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "TABLE%", new String[]{"TABLE"});
while (meta.next()) {
     System.out.println(meta.getString(3));
}
```

Note that you have to specify table name pattern in upper case. Also it's good to pass table types that you need, although it is optional.

Comment: I tried this by checking the existence of `table1` table: `ResultSet rs = dbm.getTables(null, null, "table1", null); if (rs.next()) { //do something...`. But I don't even get to if block.

Comment: Check out my edit above, looks like you need to pass table name in upper cacse

Comment: Yes, I tried table names in upper case and this code started to work :)

Comment: Good to hear that :) If you're satisfied with either of the answers, consider marking it as accepted, so that anyone who stumbles on this question knows what worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, like @Dragon said, you should search with upper cases even if you created them with lower cases.

Comment: Yea the uppercase thing is annoying. If you inspect an H2 or HSQLDB with a DBA tool you'll see that all tables and columns are in all caps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a check I used to (re)create the H2 database:

```
// IMPORTANT A sorted list of table names.
private static final String[] REQUIRED_TABLES = { "USER", ... };
public static final String CREATE_USER = "create table USER (...)";

private boolean schemaExists() throws SQLException {
  final List<String> requiredTables = Arrays.asList(REQUIRED_TABLES);
  final List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<String>();

  final Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
  try {
    final Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    final ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("show tables");
    while (rs.next()) {
      tableNames.add(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
    }
    rs.close();
    st.close();
  }
  finally {
    if (conn != null) { conn.close(); }
  }

  Collections.sort(tableNames);
  return tableNames.equals(requiredTables);
}

private void initializeDatabase() throws SQLException {
  final Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
  try {
    if (schemaExists()) {
      return;
    }

    final Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate(CREATE_USER);
    conn.commit();
  }
  finally {
    if (conn != null) { conn.close(); }
  }
}
```

And you just call:

```
  initializeDatabase();
```

Notice the list of required tables has to be sorted because I use `List.equals()` to compare two lists. It would probably be better to also programmatically sort the required tables list too.

It's not fool-proof (not checking if any table exists and if it should be altered) but it works for me.

Take a look at the [SHOW](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#show) command for other uses.